# Labview MongoDB Driver on top of C# Driver. No GetCollection Method

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, labview

I'm writting a labview driver for MongoDB on top of C# driver 2.10.2 (I know there is a version from 5 years ago) through the .net framework. Everything was going well until I wanted to create the method to get a collection. As you see in the picture, I can't get the method GetCollection from IMongoDatabase object (but I can get the CreateColection...). I don't know why there are missing methods.

[image: Labview missing methods]

I have downloaded the source code from [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases) (the tar.gz file). I compiled it with visual studio 2019 (Release, AnyCPU) and then get the DLLs. (There are two folders, "net452" & "netstandard1.5". I reproduced the error with DLLs from both folders. I don't know the difference between them).

I know nothing about C#, so I can't know if DLLs are ok and method works in C#. Also I know nothing about Visual Studio, I have downloaded it expressly for this project to compile the code. So maybe I have done something silly. What I have done is open the .sln file, select release instead of debug, and click compile.

Any hint where I can start search?

Thank  you so much for your help,

Héctor

EDIT: I have downloaded the version 9.2 from github that is already compiled and I have the same problem.  But if I choose the legacy driver (in both versions) it works, I have the method getCollection for the obsolte object MongoDatabase instead of the new IMongoDatabase.  What's happening here?

You can see here that the object IMongoDatabase has the getColletion method:

```
<member name="M:MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase.GetCollection``1(System.String,MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionSettings)">
  <summary> Gets a collection. </summary>
  <typeparam name="TDocument">The document type.</typeparam>
  <param name="name">The name of the collection.</param>
  <param name="settings">The settings.</param>
  <returns>An implementation of a collection.</returns>
</member>
```